# Running command on new page

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I have a special letterhead command called `\newpageheader` which adds a decorative figure and sets spacing for new pages:

```
\newcommand{\newpageheader}{\newpage \thispagestyle{plain} \hspace{-1in} \includegraphics{letterhead.png} }
```

Currently, I have to add the `\newpageheader` command deliberately, which involves finding natural breaks in the text based on the compiled PDF. This is manual and time-consuming.

Is there a way to make a command like this run on each new page automatically? My objective is for the formatting to be automatic, and not require any manual tweaks.

Comment: Always post a **complete** small document demonstrating the issue. That's much more useful than mere code fragments. In this case, a mock up of what you want might be helpful, too, since the first answer provided apparently doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be done through page styles (like `plain`, which you're setting). So, ideally one should create a letter head style, and you can use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum,graphicx}
\fancypagestyle{letterhead}{
  \setlength{\headheight}{2\baselineskip}%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=1.5\baselineskip,width=.8\textwidth]{example-image}}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\fbox{\thepage}}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-20]
\pagestyle{letterhead}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

The above image shows pages 3 and 4, even though the page style was initiated on page 4. It will remain unless changed using `\thispagestyle` or `\pagestyle`.

Note that certain commands may force a specific page style (like `\chapter` in [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report) and [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) which force a `plain` page style on the chapter page).

---

Another subtle way of introducing content on a *subsequent* page without introducing a hard, visible break, would be to utilize [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage). However, I don't think this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, @Werner. Knowledge of the fancyhdr package is helpful. Unfortunately, after playing with it for ~15 minutes I can't figure out certain key features. I'll mess around with it more later.

Comment: @TomLaGatta: There are other options to set page styles, like [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps). Not sure what your "key features" would be though...